# Detecting code source variants of the same function

Tags: javascript, antimalware, detection

Suppose I have this `JavaScript` malicious function `f1()` :

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function f1(){
 a=1;
 b=2;
 c=a+b;
}
</SCRIPT>
```

This function is embedded within a larger `JavaScript` program called `myScript`.
I use a `Python` script called `myScanner` that reads `myScript` and warns me if `f1()` is present or not.
`myScanner` works well. But I have no idea how to check all the possible forms of this malicious function in `myScript` in the case I  change the name of those variables, or simply write the source code of `f1()` in an other way but that performs the same task.
My question is: how could `myScanner` detect `f1()` whatever the changes made on it as long as it performs the same action ?

Comment: I don't know the answer but it seems a work for language processing tools: a lexer, a parser, etc. In fact I think that the problem as you have stated it may be undecidable (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable)

Comment: @kinunt Thank you for the answer, but I do not think it is undeciable as a problem since lot of products works on the same principle.

Comment: Sure, just an idea. There exist an algorithm that can establish if two fragments of code return the same value (or perform the same actions) given the same input? Is this problem decidible? That's my question. Just to be clear :)

Comment: @kinunt I am not a mathematician, I just say if it is undecidable as a problem then how come anti-viruses use signatures scan successfully ? It is the same principle highlited by my problem.

Comment: @begueradj a common technique used by malware to bypass A-V is to modify the look of existing code with packers, so to a large extent A-V signatures don't scan successfully :)

Comment: @RоryMcCune Thank you for the information. But anti-viruses use signatures and they check the variants of the same virus/worm. But this is not the problem I asked in the start :)

Comment: @begueradj Antivirus detect variants of the same virus by using other signatures/patterns for the variants, NOT analyzing the behaviour of a code and identifying the same exact behaviour in another code.

Comment: @kinunt But the signatures of malicious JavaScript code are simply the malicious code itself, am I right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an undecidable problem. It is as difficult as the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

You can see the question and answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487045/can-an-algorithm-analyze-the-behaviour-of-a-function-and-say-if-another-function